disable auto-scrolling outside window
Something has been bothering me for a while on ubuntu (I use Xubuntu hence xfce), and I will try to explain the best I can.
When I open a pdf and select (or copy) some text, if I move the mouse outside the pdf viewer window (here Evince, but also occurring in Atril) and then move the cursor up or down with my mouse, then the pdf page keeps scrolling.
Very annoying, because when I move my mouse to another screen, then the pdf keeps scrolling indefinitely on the other screen !
What is at stake here, and how can I disable this behavior ?
If I'm not clear enough (maybe a stupid question) here is a gif:

Here are some details (vanilla xubuntu 24.04.1 LTS):
$ uname -a
Linux p5570 6.8.0-48-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 27 14:04:52 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

$ wmctrl -m
Name: Xfwm4
Class: xfwm4
PID: 4048
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: N/A

$ xfwm4 --version
    This is xfwm4 version 4.18.0 (revision 7e7473c5b) for Xfce 4.18
    Released under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
    Compiled against GTK+-3.24.41, using GTK+-3.24.41.

    Build configuration and supported features:
    - Startup notification support:                 Yes
    - XSync support:                                Yes
    - Render support:                               Yes
    - Xrandr support:                               Yes
    - Xpresent support:                             Yes
    - X Input 2 support:                            No
    - Embedded compositor:                          Yes
    - Epoxy support:                                Yes

$ gtk-launch  --version
3.24.41

$ gtk4-launch --version
4.14.2


